# How can I use the PCL visualizer (Windows) and avoid the WM_QUIT message closing my application when the visualizer closes

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am using the PCL visualizer saveScreenshot() to create a png of my pointcloud. That's all working, but when I call viewer.close(), the Windows implementation calls TerminateApp which sends a WM_QUIT that closes my application. What I want to happen is the visualizer window close and have my application continue.

I don't need any user interaction with the visualizer window. I'm just using it to get the .png from the pointcloud.

I tried initializing the visualizer without an interactor, but saveScreenshot() doesn't work with a null interactor.

Is there some way to set up the interactor without a message proc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pcl::io::savePNGFile()`](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/group__io.html#gafa3ba367002df2314a3e38af7377abf2) to export a PNG directly from your program

Comment: I have an unorganized PointXYZRGB cloud. When I call pcl::io::savePNGFile(cloud, file, "z") I get [pcl::io::savePNGFile] Failed to extract an image from "z" field.

Comment: I figured out how to use setPointCloudRenderingProperties(PCL_VISUALIZER_LUT and LUT_RANGE with the visualizer saveScreenShot() to create depth png of my point cloud. Still haven't figured out how to avoid the WM_QUIT so as a hack I have the visualizer in another program that I shell out to. Not a great solution but that's all I can get to work.

Comment: From the header: `void pcl::io::savePNGFile(const std::string & file_name, const pcl::PointCloud<PointT> & cloud, const std::string & field_name)`
So you should call `pcl::io::savePNGFile(file, cloud, "z")`

Answer (score 0):

Can savePNGFile use camera intrinsics? Would I add camera intrinsics to the cloud to get the PNG I want?